# Pass binding to child view in init SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I need to save an instance of a child view into a variable, so I can call a method on it afterward.

However, I need to pass a binding into this child view when its initialized. How do I do that?

```
struct EditImageView: View {

    @State private var currentSelectedText:String
    @State private var currentSelectedFilter:Filter
    var imageCanvasView: ImageCanvasView

    init() {
        currentSelectedText = "Hello"
        currentSelectedFilter = Filter.noFilter
        imageCanvasView = ImageCanvasView(imageText: $currentSelectedText, filter: $currentSelectedFilter) 
        //Error: 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
    }

    var body: some View {
        imageCanvasview
        Button("Take screenshot") {
            imageCanvasview.takeScreenshot()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to declare `imageCanvasView` in `body`, like:

```
struct EditImageView: View {

    @State private var currentSelectedText = "Hello"
    @State private var currentSelectedFilter = Filter.noFilter
  
    var body: some View {
        let imageCanvasView = ImageCanvasView(imageText: $currentSelectedText, filter: $currentSelectedFilter)
        VStack {
            imageCanvasView
            Button("Take screenshot") {
                imageCanvasView.takeScreenshot()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good approach. But what if my view is more complicated? 

e.g. if imageCanvasView is nested in another HStack within that VStack, so it isn't a peer of Button. Thus the local variable imageCanvasView would be out of scope when we're at Button.

Comment: @thecanteen `imageCanvasView` is always in scope in `body`, no matter how much nesting there is.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread and thought you had defined imageCanvasView inside the VStack. This makes a lot of sense. I had no idea you could define variables inside body but I guess it's still kosher -- since body still remains a pure function

Comment: @thecanteen you could also declare variables in `ViewBuilder` functions (also conditional branching is allowed)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change the property wrapper prefix. For example, if you wanted to pass your `currentSelectedText` you would pass it like so.

```
var currentSelectedText: Binding<String> 
// Effectively is the equivalent of `@State`
```

The same can be done in your `init()`

```
init(someString: Binding<String>) { ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way is to use a view model which both `EditImageView` and `ImageCanvasView` use, something like:

```
class EditImageViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentSelectedText: String = "Hello"
    @Published var currentSelectedFilter = Filter.noFilter
    
    func takeScreenshot() {
        
    }
}

struct ImageCanvasView: View {
  
    @EnvironmentObject var editImage: EditImageViewModel
    
    var body: some View {}
}


struct EditImageView: View {
    
    @StateObject var editImage = EditImageViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ImageCanvasView()
            Button("Take screenshot") {
                editImage.takeScreenshot()
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(editImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you are adding takeScreenshot() into the ViewModel?

Comment: @thecanteen yes, that would be the proper MVVM approach, the view tells the view model the user had an intention, which then tells the model to do something. Any changes to the model as a result would then bubble back up from the VM to the view if appropriate.